# Como usar os colliders no unity?

Tags: script, unity3d, scripting

Eu estou a criar um pequeno jogo de basketball, mas tou a ter dificuldade em fazer o sistema de pontos neste caso (2 e 3).

Neste momento estou a tentar com Colliders e estou a ter dificuldade em juntar os dois:

```
public class ponto2 : MonoBehaviour {


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        ScoringSystem.theScore += 2;
    }


public class ponto3 : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        ScoringSystem.theScore += 3;
    }
```

Como faço para adicionar um collider que quando tocar nele mude para 3 em vez de 2.

Answer (score 0):

Tem vários jeitos que você poderia tentar fazer, talvez medir a distância que foi arremessada a bola até a cesta ou fazer apenas um Collider circular dentro da área de 2 pontos, logo se o player estiver nesse collider a pontuação que ele pode fazer é 2 pontos, caso contrário é 3.

```
    // Player Dentro do collider de 2 pontos
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player") other.GetComponent<SuaClasseParaoPlayer>().Pontuacao = 2;
}
// Player saiu do collider de 2 pontos
     void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player") other.GetComponent<SuaClasseParaoPlayer>().Pontuacao = 3;
}
```